# Can I reuse a Spring MVC View instance?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I created a custom view that uses Json.Simple to serialize the model and write the JSON to the response directly.

For some requests, I need to send back a static JSON message, so I am wondering can I reuse a View instance I created earlier (with the message already set)?

My View class is thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  As long as you make sure it's thread-safe, as you say, there's no reason that your controller can't return the same `View` object multiple times. Unorthodox, but valid.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem in reusing an already created view since the `render` method gets current `response` object.